# How to Dismiss all push and presented screens with single button action

Tags: ios, swift, dismiss, presentviewcontroller

I having 3 Viewcontrollers `HomePageController`, `ChangePasswordViewController`, `PasswordChangedDoneController`

in Home page changepassword button action I push the screen into `ChangePasswordViewController`.

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChangePasswordViewController")as! ChangePasswordViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Now I am present the screen `ChangePasswordViewController` to `PasswordChangedDoneController`.

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PasswordChangedController")as! PasswordChangedDoneController
self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

now I want to go to `HomePageController` with the Gotit Button Action inside of `PasswordChangedDoneController`.
Here I want to remove both push and present at a time with single action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to pop to given controller's class type

```
extension UIViewController {

    /// like UIViewController.popToRoot
    public func popToRoot() {
        guard let navigationController = navigationController else { return  dismiss(animated: true) }
        navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }

    /// like UIViewController.popTo(:)
    public func popTo(_ vc: UIViewController.Type, _ orPopToRoot: Bool = true) {
        guard let navigationController = navigationController else { return popToRoot() }
        let list = navigationController.viewControllers.reversed().filter { return $0.isKind(of: vc) }
        guard let c = list.first else {
            if orPopToRoot { self.popToRoot() }
            else { self.popSelf(animated: true) }
            return
        }
        navigationController.popToViewController(c, animated: true)
    }

    /// like UIViewController.popViewController
    ///
    /// - Note: if can't found navigationController. will 'dismiss(animated:completion:)'
    public func popSelf(animated: Bool) {
        guard let navigationController = navigationController else { return  dismissSelf(animated: animated) }
        navigationController.popViewController(animated: animated)
    }

    /// like UIViewController.dismiss
    public func dismissSelf(animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        dismiss(animated: animated, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

---

:)

Comment: 'base' is namespace for me , you can ignore it. and 'popToRoot()'  is navigation contoller's 'popToRootContoller'

Comment: I unable to get this method in presented screen button action.

Comment: you can add an extension for UIViewController , and call the method in button's selector method.

Comment: I getting these errors 
Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'popToRoot'.    
Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'popSelf'